# Pass argument asynchronously in my object c#

Tags: c#

I have got a button in windows form application c# code which calls a created object called capturer. My code is the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      obj = new Capturer(dirPath + name + "_" + surname, switcher);
}
```

The default value of switcher (boolean variable) is false. I want to change this value of switcher using the right click and pass it to the object real-time. I want the object to be updated every time the click is pressed. In order to detect mouse click events I have the following code:

```
 private void mouseClick1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Mouse clicked");
            switcher = true; 
        }
    }
```

How can I pass the variable in my object asynchronously?

Comment: You need to set a property or call a method on the `Capturer` object whenever you want to change that setting, or you can pass something other than a `bool` value, which has notification support etc.

Comment: I don't see any asynchronous/multithreaded code there... (Button clicks are not asynchronous.)

Comment: Ok I thought that mouseclick event would be only in the form code, however it seems that I can add it in the Capturer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple solutions to your problem. The easiest one ist to make `switcher` accessible outside of `Capturer` *after* creation. For instance you could turn it into a property:

```
public class Capturer
{
    public Capturer(string path, bool switcher)
    {
        Switcher = switcher;
        ...
     }

    public bool Switcher { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Inside your click handler you set the `Switcher` value:

```
private void mouseClick1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Mouse clicked");
        obj.Switcher = true; 
    }
}
```

---

In case you don't want to share the `Capturer` instance `obj` between `button1_Click()` and `mouseClick1()` you can also pass in a custom type into the `Capturer` constructor instead of a primitive value. If you save the reference to that type in your form you can change it anytime and your `Capturer` instance will pick up the changed value.

```
public class Switcher
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Capturer` constructor will look like this:

```
public Capturer(string path, Switcher switcher)
{
    this.switcher = switcher;
    ...
}
```

Inside the `Capturer` make sure you always access the switcher value through the `Switcher` instance. I.e. always use `switcher.Value` to get it.

You can create the `Switcher` instance inside your button handler...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switcher = new Switcher();
    obj = new Capturer(dirPath + name + "_" + surname, switcher);
}
```

...and set it in your click handler:

```
private void mouseClick1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Mouse clicked");
        switcher.Value = true; 
    }
}
```

This way you only have to share the `Switcher` instance between you handlers, but not the `Capturer` instance. Which solution is better depends on the way you want to structure your application and which parts should be coupled and which should be decoupled.

---

A third solution is to use a lambda, a delegate or an event.

Comment: Accepted since is the most complete answer! Thanks @Abbondanza

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new object on every mouse click will not help performance. 
You might want to create a Capturer in the Form constructor, then call a method on it on a right mouse click.

The name Capturer suggests you're trying to implement an observer pattern, but that's not exactly what's happening here; the form is the observer here, and the Capturer should be responsible for your business logic - and have a name explaining its purpose.

---

(unless your business case is capturing mouse clicks...)